# how to get the parent page reference

Tags: asp.net

I have pages "first.aspx" and "second.aspx". Now  from first.aspx, using link button I'm doing " Response.Redirect()" to "Third.aspx" and simlarly from second.aspx also with link button I'm doing " Response.Redirect() to "Third.aspx". but I want to disable a button on "third.aspx" when I come from " first.aspx" only . how can i acheive this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

```
var enabled = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Contains("first.aspx");
```

Comment: From my experience, not a reliable solution because all browsers don't use the correct http headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the referrer of the request, but that might get spoofed:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

Or you can pass an url parameter.

Or if you don't want to rely on client side parameter passing, you can save the last page in the users session on the server and check that in your third.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

When coming from first.aspx redirect to Third.aspx?from=first, when coming from second.aspx redirect to Third.aspx?from=second, then use the get parameter to disable/enable your button

Comment: none of these opproaches is working? For window.open we can pass these querystring reference but response.redirect it is not working. @Justin to try your i'm using 2003 visual studio I don't have after urlrefernce.tostring(). there is nothing like contains property

Comment: Page.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() is not giving me any page reference. I know it works. But for response.redirect it not working

Answer (score 0):

On Third.aspx, check the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Add a query parameter to indicate which page you came from:

```
Response.Redirect('third.aspx?referrer=first');
```

and

```
Response.Redirect('third.aspx?referrer=second');
```

in third:

```
if (Request["referrer"] == "first"){
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @Justin Niessner's response, but an alternative method would be instead of using a `Response.Redirect` to use the `PostBackUrl` property of the button in question. This would cause the page to "post" to the third.aspx page, and from there you would have access to `Page.PreviousPage'. More information on Previous page can be [found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

**Edit:**
A bonus to using the `PostBackUrl` property is that it will invoke the standard .Net validation controls and will help prevent the spoofing mentioned by @Jan. It doesn't make it impossible, but it certainly makes it more difficult.